# Why is my output apart of another output?

Tags: java

My output is grouping with another pair of output and that output won't print at all.
The input that isn't working at all is (f,i) and the grouped pair input is (c,c).

*Note I believe that it has something to do with the `if()` statements.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class AnnualClimate{

public static void main (String [] args)
{ //Declare and intialize variables - programmer to provide initial values
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String city = "Daytona Beach";
    String state = "Florida";
    int o=0;
    int u=0;
    int y=0;
    int t=0;
    int z=0;
    int m=0;
    double [] celsius;      
    int i = 0;
    int index=0;
    double [] average1c;
    double [] average2c;
    double [] average1;
    double [] average2;
    String month [] ={"Jan", "Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"};
    double temperature [] = {58.4,60.0,64.7,68.9,74.8,79.7,81.7,81.5,79.9,74.0,67.0,60.8};        
    double precipitation [] ={3.1, 2.7,3.8,2.5,3.3,5.7,5.2,6.1,6.6,4.5,3.0,2.7};    
    String tempLabel = "F";   //initialize to F
    String precipLabel = "inch"; //initialize to inch             

    //INPUT - ask user for temp and preciptation scale choice
    System.out.print("Choose the temperature scale (F = Fahrenheit, C = Celsius): ");
    String tempChoice = in.next();
    System.out.print("Choose the precipitation scale (i = inches, c = centimeteres): ");
    String precipChoice = in.next();

   //PROCESSING - convert from F to C and in to cm based on user's choices

    // remember 5/9 = 0, 5.0/9 = .5555
    average1c = new double[temperature.length];
    celsius = new double[temperature.length];
    average2c = new double[precipitation.length];
    average1 = new double[temperature.length];
    average2 = new double[temperature.length];

    if(tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
        tempLabel="(C)";
        for( index = 0; index < temperature.length;)
        {
           celsius[index]= (temperature[index]-32) * 5/9;
           average1[index]= celsius[index]/12;
           index++;               
        }
    }

    //Convert in values to cm; replace the current values in precipitation
    double[] centimeters = new double[ precipitation.length ];
    if(precipChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
    {
        precipLabel="(cm)";
        for ( i= 0; i<precipitation.length; i++)
        {
            centimeters[i]= precipitation[i]* 2.54;
            average2[i]=centimeters[i]/12;
        }
    }

        for( z=0; z < temperature.length; z++)
        {
            average1[z]= temperature[z]/12;
        }
        for( m=0; m < temperature.length; m++)
        {
            average1[m]= temperature[m]/12;
        }
    //OUTPUT - print table using printf to format and align data

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Climate Data");
    System.out.println("Location: " + city +", " + state);
    System.out.printf("%5s %18s %s %18s %s","Month","Temperature",tempLabel,"Precipitation",precipLabel);
    System.out.printf("%n");
    System.out.printf("***************************************************");

    while ( o< month.length){            
     if(tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")){
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.printf(month[o]);
        System.out.printf("%20.2f", celsius[o]);
        System.out.printf("%25.2f", precipitation[o]);
        o++;   
    }      
}

 while ( u< month.length){            
     if(tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("c") & (precipChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))){
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.printf(month[u]);
        System.out.printf("%20.2f", celsius[u]);
        System.out.printf("%25.2f", centimeters[u]);
        u++;   
    }      
}    
while (y< month.length){

     if(tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("f") & (precipChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("c")))
    {
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.printf(month[y]);
        System.out.printf("%20.2f",temperature [y]);
        System.out.printf("%25.2f", centimeters[y]);
        y++;
    }      
}

   while ( t< month.length){
     if(tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("f") & (precipChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("i"))){
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.printf(month[t]);
        System.out.printf("%20.2f",temperature [t]);
        System.out.printf("%25.2f", precipitation[t]);
        t++;   
    }      
}
    System.out.println();
    System.out.printf("***************************************************");
    System.out.println();

   while (y< month.length)
    {            
     if(tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("f") & (precipChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("c")))
    {
        System.out.printf("%n");            
        System.out.printf("%20.2f", average1 );
        System.out.printf("%25.2f", average2c);
        y++;   
    }  
}
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to go through with very little direction. To help us provide a timely and thorough answer, we'd appreciate as little code as possible to replicate your error and a description of what the application is trying to achieve (not simply output). `(f,i)` and `(c,c)` probably mean something to you, but nothing to us.

Comment: @user Next time, please remove all the unwanted spaces and put up the code with proper formatting. Its easier to read that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for a debugger.

Your first problem is with your "month" loop

```
while (o < month.length) {

    if (tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.printf(month[o]);
        System.out.printf("%20.2f", celsius[o]);
        System.out.printf("%25.2f", precipitation[o]);
        o++;
    }
}
```

If `tempChoice` is `F` then `o` is never updated, meaning you get yourself into a never ending loop.

I would suggest you use a `for-loop` instead, for example...

```
for (o = 0; o < month.length; o++) {

    if (tempChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
        System.out.printf("%n");
        System.out.printf(month[o]);
        System.out.printf("%20.2f", celsius[o]);
        System.out.printf("%25.2f", precipitation[o]);
    }

}
```

Then using a good IDE, add some breakpoints and start debugging you code...This is in invaluable skill you should start learning ASAP ;)